# Hadoop S3A filesystem, abort object upload?

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, parquet, parquet-mr

I have code like

```
ParquetWriter<Record> writer = getParquetWriter("s3a://my_bucket/my_object_path.snappy.parquet");
for (Record r : someIterable) {
   validate(r);
   writer.write()
}
writer.close();
```

if `validate` throws an exception, I want to release all resources associated with the writer.  But I don't want to create any objects in S3 in that case.  Is this achievable?

If I close the writer it will conclude the s3 multipart upload and create an object in the cloud.  If I don't close it, the parts written so far will remain in the disk buffer, clogging up the works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is a problem. It's been discussed in [HADOOP-16906](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-16906) *Add some Abortable.abort() interface for streams etc which can be terminated*

Problem here is it's not enough to add to the `S3ABlockOutputStream` class, we'd need to pass it through the FSDataOutputStream etc, specify it in the FS APIs, define semantics if the passthrough doesn't work, commit to maintaining it etc. A lot of effort. If you do want to do that though, patches welcome...

Keep an eye on [HDFS-13934](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-13934), multipart upload API. This will let you do the upload and then commit/abort it. Doesn't quite fit your workflow.

Afraid you will have to go with the upload. Do remember to set a lifecycle rule for the bucket to delete old uploads, and look at the `hadoop s3guard uploads` command to list/abort them too.